# getting wrong string value from NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using AVPlayer. And I want to get current time of player to show for user.
The problem is the string getting wrong value from NSDate you can see in images

[image]

This is date value

[image]

And this string value getting from date

please help to solve. this is my code

```
NSDate* d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:CMTimeGetSeconds(mPlayer.currentTime)];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];

    NSString* result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:d];
    avPlayerLabel.text = result;
```

Comment: Time passes while the compiler compiles the code, so the current time changes by a few seconds. That's why you're getting different values.

Comment: @Neeku While compiling?  Huh?

Comment: @Droppy What's unclear for you?

Comment: @Neeku :Assigning from the defined data(date), so how come **Time passes while the compiler compiles the code**

Comment: Right, my bad! Ignore it! :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need an `NSDateFormatter`:

```
Float64 time = CMTimeGetSeconds(mPlayer.currentTime) + 0.5;
unsigned minutes = (unsigned)time / 60;
unsigned seconds = (unsigned)time % 60;
avPlayerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u", minutes, seconds];
```

Comment: @AltafBangash I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean that actual video's duration is 7 seconds but here they goes up to 6 seconds.

Comment: @AltafBangash Have you confirmed that by looking at the value of the `time` variable in the debugger?

Comment: Yes, actually that goes up to 6.8 seconds but I don't know how we can get ceil value in that case

Comment: @AltafBangash I've added a simple fix to get to the nearest second.